# Count time stamps in different time intervals - issue with interval which spans midnight

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I have a dataframe ("observations") with time stamps in `H:M` format ("Time"). In a second dataframe ("intervals"), I have time ranges defined by "From" and "Till" variables, also in `H:M` format.

I want to count number of observations which falls within each interval. I have been using `between` from `data.table`, which has been working without any problem when dates are included.

However, now I only have time stamps, without date. This causes some problems for the times which occurs in the interval which spans midnight (`20:00 - 05:59`). These times are not counted in the code I have tried.

Example below

```
interval.data <- data.frame(From = c("14:00", "20:00", "06:00"), Till = c("19:59", "05:59", "13:59"), stringsAsFactors = F)
observations <- data.frame(Time = c("14:32", "15:59", "16:32", "21:34", "03:32", "02:00", "00:00", "05:57", "19:32", "01:32", "02:22", "06:00", "07:50"), stringsAsFactors = F)

interval.data
#        From     Till
# 1: 14:00:00 19:59:00
# 2: 20:00:00 05:59:00 # <- interval including midnight
# 3: 06:00:00 13:59:00

observations
#        Time
#  1: 14:32:00
#  2: 15:59:00
#  3: 16:32:00
#  4: 21:34:00 # Row 4-8 & 10-11 falls in 'midnight interval', but are not counted
#  5: 03:32:00 # 
#  6: 02:00:00 #
#  7: 00:00:00 #
#  8: 05:57:00 #
#  9: 19:32:00
# 10: 01:32:00 # 
# 11: 02:22:00 #
# 12: 06:00:00
# 13: 07:50:00

library(data.table)
library(plyr)
adply(interval.data, 1, function(x, y) sum(y[, 1] %between% c(x[1], x[2])), y = observations)

#    From  Till V1
# 1 14:00 19:59  4
# 2 20:00 05:59  0 # <- zero counts - wrong!
# 3 06:00 13:59  2
```

Comment: Are those always your time intervals, or is this just a smaller example of a bigger data set?

Comment: Same structure of a much bigger set

Comment: Using `adply` with a 1 margin kind of makes the use of data.table irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tweaked your code to get the desired result. Hope this helps!

```
adply(interval.data, 1, function(x, y) 
  if(x[1] > x[2]) return(sum(y[, 1] %between% c(x[1], 23:59), y[, 1] %between% c(00:00, x[2]))) else return(sum(y[, 1] %between% c(x[1], x[2]))), y = observations)
```

Output is:

```
   From  Till V1
1 14:00 19:59  4
2 20:00 05:59  7
3 06:00 13:59  2
```

Comment: This is perfect. Just need to quote "23:59" and "00:00". Although it did work for above example.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use a non-equi join in `data.table`, and their helper function `as.ITime` for working with time strings.

You'll have an issue with the interval that spans midnight, but, there should only ever be one of those. And as you're interested in the number of observations per 'group' of intervals, you can treat this group as the equivalent of the 'Not' of the others.

For example, first convert your `data.frame` to `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

## set your data.frames as `data.table`
setDT(interval.data)
setDT(observations)
```

Then use `as.ITime` to convert to an integer representation of time

```
## convert time stamps
interval.data[, `:=`(FromMins = as.ITime(From),
                     TillMins = as.ITime(Till))]

observations[, TimeMins := as.ITime(Time)]
## you could combine this step with the non-equi join directly, but I'm separating it for clarity
```

You can now use a non-equi join to find the interval that each time falls within. Noting that those times that reutrn 'NA' are actually those that fall inside the midnight-spanning interval

```
interval.data[
  observations
  , on = .(FromMins <= TimeMins, TillMins > TimeMins)
  ]

#      From  Till FromMins TillMins  Time
# 1:  14:00 19:59      872      872 14:32
# 2:  14:00 19:59      959      959 15.59
# 3:  14:00 19:59      992      992 16:32
# 4:     NA    NA     1294     1294 21:34
# 5:     NA    NA      212      212 03:32
# 6:     NA    NA      120      120 02:00
# 7:     NA    NA        0        0 00:00
# 8:     NA    NA      357      357 05:57
# 9:  14:00 19:59     1172     1172 19:32
# 10:    NA    NA       92       92 01:32
# 11:    NA    NA      142      142 02:22
# 12: 06:00 13:59      360      360 06:00
# 13: 06:00 13:59      470      470 07:50
```

Then to get the number of observatins for the groups of intervals, you just `.N` grouped by each time point, which can just be chained onto the end of the above statement

```
interval.data[
  observations
  , on = .(FromMins <= TimeMins, TillMins > TimeMins)
][
  , .N
  , by = .(From, Till)
]

#     From  Till N
# 1: 14:00 19:59 4
# 2:    NA    NA 7
# 3: 06:00 13:59 2
```

Where the `NA` group corresponds to the one that spans midnight

Comment: Could you use `as.ITime` here, instead of converting to minutes?

Comment: @Henrik - ah yes, of course! I always for get about `ITime` in `data.table`... I'll update